# Automatic size in custom table columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have made this fully custom data table to display some content dynamically, you can manually change column size and order, doing so all cells are on **absolute positioning** with **set width**.

I want to create a function that will check for the "best size" for columns depending on the contents.
Like you would do in Excel for example when you double tap on a column separator (some columns will have long descriptions inside, some just links, etc.).

Cell will only contains texts, it can be wrapped (actually goes into ellipsis when resizing to small) and the rows allow for horizontal scrolling so there is no limitation on this side.

But so far I have no clue on how I can manage to do that, do you have any lead ?

[image]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask tthis question is lacking code

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `best size`? Let assume the `contents` are just plain texts. Do we allow these texts to be wrapped? Does the total columns' width need to fill the entire width of the parent?

Comment: I've updated my question so: yes cell contains only text, it can be wrapped (hidden/ellipsis or break line), rows have horizontal scroll so there is no limitation for the size (columns should take at least the size of the viewport but it can go over it)